Wireguard Error: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported on CentOS 7
Our server is still on CentOS 7 and I am trying to use Wireguard on it.
While starting it, it gives:
$ sudo wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
Cannot find device "wg0"

$ uname -r
3.10.0-1160.105.1.vz7.214.3

But when I try to install $ sudo yum install linux-headers-$(uname -r) it says "no package linux-headers-3.10.0-1160.105.1.vz7.214.3".
Checking what is installed:
$ sudo yum list installed | grep headers
glibc-headers.x86_64                    2.17-292.el7                @base       
kernel-headers.x86_64                   3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7        @updates

My config
[Interface]
Address = 10.5.5.1/24
ListenPort = <port>
# Use your own private key, from /etc/wireguard/privatekey
PrivateKey = <private key>

[Peer]
# Workstation public key
PublicKey = <pub key>
# VPN client's IP address in the VPN
AllowedIPs = 10.5.5.2/32

[Peer]
# laptop public key
PublicKey = <pub key>
# VPN client's IP address in the VPN
AllowedIPs = 10.5.5.3/32

How can I safely install the matching header? Is the header's version mismatch very likely the reason for this kind of error?
I am confused by the message Protocol not supported and I don't know, whether it also points to a version mismatch.

Protocol not supported the EOL platform security lib isn't compatible with the security lib  protocol specifier bits. Time to upgrade.

You need either kernel 5.6 or higher, or you can try older wireguard. You could try wireguard-LTS or wireguard-dkms with Linux headers, that that might work, as it will compiled the libraries during install instead of using prebuilt versions. Re headers: what’s a .vz7 kernel? Doesn’t seem normal. Is that provided by centos? Yum search Linux headers first, if not found, you may need to get a different kernel version that has headers in the repos. Or maybe your yum sources just need uncommenting for package-source. Check that too.

There is wireguard-go, a statically built userspace implementation. Try it. (Pretty much single advantage of WireGuard was that it runs in kernel space; this defeats the purpose. Why not use OpenVPN then?) That said, ancient unsupported systems are off topic.

@RobertGlonek Mhm, even older? Because of wg --version  # -> wireguard-tools v1.0.20210914, so it is also 3 years old. vz7 seems to be part of a distribution from/via/?? OpenVZ, used by an old linux virtualization platform: Virtuozzo leverages OpenVZ as its core of a virtualization solution. I am checking the wireguard-dkms thing.

@BairDev just 3 years? Now let’s do the same for your 3.10 kernel: Linux 3.10 has been released on Sun, 30 Jun 2013. That’s 11 years. It reached end of life November 8, 2017. That’s 6 years ago. Your kernel reached end of life 3 years before your wireguard was developed and released.
